I want to add new node to elasticsearch cluster and executed "elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node".I got error
I want to add new node to elasticsearch cluster and so executed "elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node" on existing cluster.I got error as below:
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.12.198.96 found
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:160) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:101) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:457) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:431) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.common.ssl.DiagnosticTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(DiagnosticTrustManager.java:80) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1302) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1195) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1138) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[?:?]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[?:?]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:586) ~[?:?]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187) ~[?:?]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:141) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.common.socket.SocketAccess.lambda$doPrivileged$0(SocketAccess.java:42) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.common.socket.SocketAccess.doPrivileged(SocketAccess.java:41) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.CommandLineHttpClient.execute(CommandLineHttpClient.java:178) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.CommandLineHttpClient.execute(CommandLineHttpClient.java:112) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.tool.BaseRunAsSuperuserCommand.checkClusterHealthWithRetries(BaseRunAsSuperuserCommand.java:214) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.tool.BaseRunAsSuperuserCommand.execute(BaseRunAsSuperuserCommand.java:127) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-8.11.4.jar:8.11.4]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-cli-8.11.4.jar:8.11.4]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50) ~[elasticsearch-cli-8.11.4.jar:8.11.4]
at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64) ~[cli-launcher-8.11.4.jar:8.11.4]
ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster. , with exit code 69
I am expecting token to be generated,but got error

are you using custom generated SSL certificate  (self signed certificate) ?

what configuration you have for network.host and network.publish_host for new node and existing node ?
